# Python - AttributeError: 'Particle' object has no attribute 'display'

Tags: python, object, attributes, attributeerror

This question is asked a lot, but unfortunately I found no answer fitting my problem. If possible, I prefer a generic answer, since I'm a novice trying to learn Python. Thank you in advance.

This is the code I got by following a tutorial on the basics of python using the pygame library:

```
import pygame

background_colour = (255, 255, 255)
(width, height) = (300, 200)


class Particle:
    def __init__(self, x, y, size):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.colour = (0, 0, 255)
        self.thickness = 1


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))


def display(self):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.colour, (self.x, self.y), self.size,  self.thickness)


pygame.display.set_caption('Agar')
screen.fill(background_colour)
pygame.display.flip()

running = True
my_first_particle = Particle(150, 50, 15)
my_first_particle.display()
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

It is used to create a window for gaming, with a circle in it. The circle is defined as a class to be used multiple times in a similar way later on.

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/20172542/PycharmProjects/agarTryout/Agar.py", line 29, in <module>
    my_first_particle.display()
AttributeError: 'Particle' object has no attribute 'display'
```

What principle am I not understanding, and what is the specific solution for this error?

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Your `Particle` class doesn't define a `display` method. Did you mean to call `display` on something else? Perhaps `pygame`?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking - the error is clear. You're calling a nonexistent method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `display` function defined is not inside Particle, instead at the `global` (not sure if this name is right) level of your script. Indentation is significant in python, as it does not have brackets. Move the function after your `__init__` function, with the same indentation.

Also, I guess you should move `screen` above your `Particle` definition.

Answer (score 0):

By your definition of the Particle class, my_first_particle (an instance of Particle) has no display attribute.

It looks like the definition of the display function should be part of the Particle class definition.

Check out the Python Classes tutorial.